# Converting Arraylist implementation to universal in C

Tags: c, arraylist, implementation, generic-programming, universal

I have implemented ArrayList in plain C.

**HEADER (arraylist.h):**

```
#pragma once

struct ArrayListImpl;
typedef int LISTTYPE;
typedef struct ArrayListImpl ArrayList;

ArrayList* new_ArrayList(int iSize);
void destroy(ArrayList* list);

int indexOf(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element);
void add(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element);
void addBefore(ArrayList* list, int index, LISTTYPE element);
void clear(ArrayList* list);
_Bool contains(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element);
_Bool removeEl(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element);
void removeFrom(ArrayList* list, int index);
void set(ArrayList* list, int index, LISTTYPE element);
int size(ArrayList* list);
void print(ArrayList* list);
void printInfo(ArrayList* list);
```

**IMPLEMENTATION (arraylist.c):**

```
#include "arraylist.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ArrayListImpl
{
    int size, buffer, origBuffer;
    LISTTYPE* data;
};

void incBuffer(ArrayList* list)
{
    if (list->size == list->buffer)
    {
        list->buffer = (int)(list->buffer * 1.5 + 1);
        list->data = (LISTTYPE*)realloc(list->data, sizeof(LISTTYPE) * list->buffer);
    }
}

void decBuffer(ArrayList* list)
{
    if (list->size < list->buffer / 2.5 && list->buffer > list->origBuffer)
    {
        list->buffer = max(list->origBuffer, list->buffer / 2);
        list->data=(LISTTYPE*)realloc(list->data, sizeof(LISTTYPE) * list->buffer);
    }
}
void resetBuffer(ArrayList* list)
{
    list->buffer = list->origBuffer;
    list->data = (LISTTYPE*)realloc(list->data, sizeof(LISTTYPE) * list->buffer);
}

ArrayList* new_ArrayList(int buffer)
{
    ArrayList* out;
    out = (ArrayList*)malloc(sizeof out);
    out->size = 0;
    out->buffer = buffer;
    out->origBuffer = buffer;
    out->data = (LISTTYPE*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(LISTTYPE));
    return out;
}

void destroy(ArrayList* list)
{
    free(list->data);
}

int indexOf(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list->size; ++i)
    {
        if (list->data[i] == element)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void add(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element)
{
    incBuffer(list);
    list->data[list->size++] = element;
}

void addBefore(ArrayList* list, int from, LISTTYPE element)
{
    if (from < 0 || from > list->size)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Trying to add before %d. element of list having size %d\n", from, list->size);
        return;
    }
    incBuffer(list);
    ++list->size;
    for (int i = list->size; i > from; --i)
    {
        list->data[i] = list->data[i - 1];
    }
    list->data[from] = element;
}

_Bool removeEl(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element)
{
    int id = indexOf(list, element);
    if (id == -1)
        return 0;
    --list->size;
    for (int i = id; i < list->size; ++i)
    {
        list->data[i] = list->data[i + 1];
    }
    decBuffer(list);
    return 1;
}

void removeFrom(ArrayList* list, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= list->size)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Trying to remove %d. element of list having size %d\n", index, list->size);
        return;
    }
    --list->size;
    for (int i = index; i < list->size; ++i)
    {
        list->data[i] = list->data[i + 1];
    }
    decBuffer(list);
}

_Bool contains(ArrayList* list, LISTTYPE element)
{
    return indexOf(list, element) != -1;
}

int size(ArrayList* list)
{
    return list->size;
}

void clear(ArrayList* list)
{
    list->size = 0;
    resetBuffer(list);
}

void set(ArrayList* list, int index, LISTTYPE element)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= list->size)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Trying to set %d. element of list having size %d\n", index, list->size);
        return;
    }
    list->data[index] = element;
}

void print(ArrayList* list)
{
    printf("--- ArrayList ---\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < list->size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d.: %dn", i, list->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n-------------------\n");
}

void printInfo(ArrayList* list)
{
    printf("--- ArrayList INFO ---\nSize: %d\nElement size : %d\nBuffer : %d\n", list->size, sizeof(int), list->buffer);
}
```

As you can see it only works with data having type of LISTTYPE defined in the header file. My question would be that how can I make it working universally with any kind of data type? So for example add the LISTTYPE somehow to it's constructor instead of it's header. Is it possible to do it, or at least do something like that in plain C and not in C++?

Comment: Yes, but what exactly? I couldn't really find any solution yet, that's why I am asking it here.

Comment: You have several functions accepting parameters of type `LISTTYPE`.  The data type of C function parameters is part of the type of the function that contains them, and is therefore fixed at the time that the function is compiled.  You cannot change it without recompiling the function.

Comment: The usual approach for something like this would be to have the list store pointers to elements instead of the elements themselves.  You can then use type `void *` for those pointers, and the user would need to convert them to the appropriate pointer type before dereferencing them.  One could conceivably write macro wrappers to assist with all that.

Comment: Note also that the distinction between storing pointers to elements and storing the elements themselves fades significantly when the elements are strings or otherwise are already pointers.  One can, of course, create and store pointers to pointers, but one could also store the original pointers directly.

Comment: I know how void * works, however as you can see in my source code, if I replace the LISTTYPE* to void*, then I will have serious issues with dereferencing them for example on adding an element to the list.

Comment: You've misunderstood me, @gyurix.  In particular, you seem not to have caught the implications of "store pointers to elements instead of the elements themselves."  That would mean converting not `LISTTYPE *` but `LISTTYPE` to `void *`.  There would be no dereferencing of `void *`.

Comment: So I should do something like void**? But how would that handle things properly if I use it with equivalent objects having different addresses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157022/discussion-between-gyurix-and-john-bollinger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must separate the concerns of your internal list management from those of your customer's list data.  Your list management data must be strongly typed, but your view of the customer's list data should be opaque (void*).  Your interface design should preserve this separation of concerns.

There is no need to declare or define ArrayListImpl in arraylist.h.  Your customers don't need to know about it. Having an ArrayList type is good, but it would suffice if it were simply an opaque handle implemented as an index value, hash or data pointer (void*).  Basically, whatever you give your customers for tracking their list, they should be unable to learn any implementation details from its declaration or use.  If you do hand them a pointer to an internal management structure, their view of it should be void*.  You can always cast from void* to whatever your internal data structure is.

I recommend that you rethink your interface.  Write some unit tests using just the ArrayList.h file and get them to compile (they obviously won't link).  Get a feel for how your interface will be used from your customer's perspective.  Also, add comments to your header file.  We shouldn't have to guess whether iSize is to specify the size of the array, the number of elements or the size of an element.  It would probably be more practical if customers specified a count and element size when initializing a list.

Some example code:

In ArrayList.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// The current implementation of the API defined herein is not thread safe.s

// ArrayList should be treated as an opaque data object, never intended
// to be dereferenced by client code.
typedef void* ArrayList;

// Define default module initialization.
#define ARRAYLIST_DEFAULT_NUM_LISTS 4
#define ARRAYLIST_DEFAULT_INCREMENT_SIZE 8

// InitializeArrayListModule(size_t numLists, size_t incrementSize);
//   Optional module initializer.  The number of lists can grow until memory
//   runs out, but performance may not be optimal and the heap can get 
//   fragmented.  
//   Call this function only if you're going to be allocating more or less 
//   than the default values.
// Arguments:
//   numLists  Number of lists the internal data structures are preallocated 
//   for. Internal
//             default is ARRAYLIST_DEFAULT_NUM_LISTS.
//   incrementSize  Number of additional internal data structures to allocate 
//   when a call to NewArrayList() triggers a realocation of data structures. 
//   Internal default is DEFAULT_INCREMENT_SIZE.
// Returns:
//   true if enough internal data structures can be allocated to support the 
//   specified number of lists.
//   false if allocations failed, the function has been called more than once 
//   or NewArrayList has
//   already been called.
// Notes:
//  1. List management data structures are stored in separate memory from 
//     client's list data.
bool InitializeArrayListModule(size_t numLists, size_t incrementSize);

// NewArrayList(size_t, size_t)
//   The only way to properly initialize an ArrayList object.
// Arguments:
//   initialCapacity Number of initial elements to allocate, must not be 
//   zero.
//   sizeofElements  Size in bytes of each element, must not be zero.
// Returns:
//   A valid ArrayList on success.
//   NULL on failure.
ArrayList NewArrayList(size_t initialCapacity, size_t sizeofElement);

// DestroyArrayList(ArrayList arrayList)
//   The only way to properly destroy an ArrayList object.
// Arguments:
//   arrayList  ArrayList object returned from NewArrayList, or NULL.
// Returns:
//   NULL.
// Example:
//   ArrayList arrayList = NewArrayList(capacity, sizeofElement);
//   arrayList = DestroyArrayList(arrayList);
ArrayList DestroyArrayList(ArrayList arrayList);

// AddArrayListItem(ArrayList, void *item)
//   Copies elementSize bytes from the memory pointed to by item.
// Arguments:
//   arrayList  A valid ArrayList object returned from NewArrayList.
//   element    Pointer to the data to add to the list.
// Returns:
//   true if successful.
bool AddArrayListItem(ArrayList arrayList, void *element);
```

In UTArrayList.c

```
    #include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "ArrayList.h"

void _UTShowTestResult(char *testFuncName, bool result)
{
    if (result)
    {
        printf("%s() passed.\n", testFuncName);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s() failed.\n", testFuncName);
    }
}

#define UTShowTestResult(funcName) _UTShowTestResult(#funcName, funcName##())

// In UTArrayList.c
// TODO: Add logging.
#include <limits.h>

// Smoke test: bool InitializeArrayListModule(size_t numLists, size_t incrementSize);
bool UTInitializeArrayListModule()
{
    return InitializeArrayListModule(1, 4);
}

// Smoke test: ArrayList NewArrayList(size_t, size_t).
bool UTNewArrayList()
{
    // Happy path...
    for (size_t capacity = 1; capacity <= (64 * 1024); capacity += 1024)
    {
        for (size_t elementSize = 1; elementSize <= (64 * 1024); elementSize += 1024)
        {
            ArrayList testList = NewArrayList(capacity, elementSize);
            if (NULL == testList)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO: Test that expected failure paths fail gracefully.

    return true;
}

// Smoke test: ArrayList DestroyArrayList(ArrayList arrayList)
bool UTDestroyArrayList()
{
    ArrayList arrayList = NewArrayList(1, 1);

    // Verify works with NULL.
    if (NULL != DestroyArrayList(NULL))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Verify works with valid arrayList object, but don't let the test overwrite it yet.
    if (NULL != DestroyArrayList(&arrayList))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Verify works twice on same value.
    arrayList = DestroyArrayList(&arrayList); // The correct way to call DestroyArrayList().
    if (NULL != arrayList)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Smoke test: bool AddArrayListItem(ArrayList arrayList, void *element)
bool UTAddArrayListItem()
{
    // TODO: Verify list items are correct and remain in proper order over 
    //       list operations, as soon we have an implementation for iterating 
    //       over the list.
    // TODO: Verify items of different sizes can added successfully.
    const char* str1 = "str1";
    ArrayList arrayList = NewArrayList(2, sizeof(char*));
    return AddArrayListItem(arrayList, str1);
}

// ArrayList Unit Test Driver.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // TODO: As the interface is fleshed out, add unit test calls.
    UTShowTestResult(UTInitializeArrayListModule);
    UTShowTestResult(UTNewArrayList);
    UTShowTestResult(UTDestroyArrayList);
    UTShowTestResult(UTAddArrayListItem);
}
```

In ArrayList.c

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

typedef struct _List 
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t elementSize;
    size_t count;
    void* data;
} List;

static size_t _listCapacity = ARRAYLIST_DEFAULT_NUM_LISTS;
static size_t _incrementSize = ARRAYLIST_DEFAULT_INCREMENT_SIZE;
static size_t _count = 0;

static List *_lists = NULL;
static List *_nextList = NULL;

// TODO: Add implementations as interfaces and unit tests are added.

static bool _InitializeModule()
{
    // Always fail to initialize twice!
    if (NULL == _lists)
    {
        _lists = calloc(_listCapacity, sizeof(List));
        _nextList = _lists;
    }
    return (_lists != NULL);
}

static bool _ReallocateLists()
{
    List *newLists = calloc(_listCapacity + _incrementSize, sizeof(List));
    if (NULL != newLists)
    {
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < _listCapacity; idx++)
        {
            newLists[idx] = _lists[idx];
        }
        List *tmp = _lists;
        _lists = newLists;
        free(tmp);
        _nextList = _lists + _listCapacity;
    }
    return (NULL != _lists);
}

bool InitializeArrayListModule(size_t numLists, size_t incrementSize)
{
    if (NULL == _lists)
    {
        _listCapacity = numLists;
        _incrementSize = incrementSize;
    }
    return _InitializeModule();
}

ArrayList NewArrayList(size_t initialCapacity, size_t sizeofElement)
{
    if (NULL == _lists)
    {
        if (!_InitializeModule()) return NULL;
    }

    if (_listCapacity < _count)
    {
        if (!_ReallocateLists()) return NULL;
    }

    List *p = &(_lists[_count]);
    p->capacity = initialCapacity;
    p->elementSize = sizeofElement;
    p->data = calloc(initialCapacity, sizeofElement);

    return p;
}

ArrayList DestroyArrayList(ArrayList arrayList)
{
    List *p = arrayList;    // Convert from void* to List*.
    List *last = _lists + _listCapacity;
    // Sanity checks...
    bool isInRange = (p >= _lists) && (p <= last);
    bool isAligned = 0 == ((p - _lists) % sizeof(List));
    if (isInRange && isAligned)
    {
        free(p->data);
        memset(p, 0, sizeof(List));
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool AddArrayListItem(ArrayList arrayList, void *item)
{
    // TODO: find the list, use similar logic to how _lists is managed, to add this item to that lists data array.
    // HINT: memcpy(itemAddress, item, sizeofElement);
    return false;
}
```

The above demonstrates that void pointers can be used as opaque data objects to shield your implementation from client data types and clients from yours.  The supplied unit tests demonstrate use of the API's from the client perspective and provides you with a playground to try out your API's and test your implementations.

Comment: Nice tips however you did not tell me basically where to use that void*. I mean that how will it become an universal / generic list type. Where should I use void* exactly in which parts of my code?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example code for using these void* at least for one of my methods, which currently dereferences the LISTTYPE*?

Comment: @gyurix I was hoping for some initiative on your part, but sure, I just wont get to it right away.

Comment: The problem is that I already tried what you said about void*s and it totally failed. It break kinda everything. Storing pointers instead of values make it impossible to work with equivalent values having different addresses, which makes the list kinda useless.

Comment: @gyurix, example code added.  When you document your interface and write unit tests for each function in the API, it helps organize your thinking and maximizes the efficiency of your efforts.  Always take baby steps.  Write the unit test for a function when you add its prototype to your API, write a skeleton implementation that fails, to back the API and verify your unit test initially fails, then flesh out the implementation until the unit test passes, then move on to the next function your API.

Comment: Note that the above code is intentionally incomplete, but I think it is sufficient to qualify as an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157087/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-gyurix).